# Why is my dryer radioactive?

Tags: everyday-life, radiation, radioactivity

My Geiger counter measures a background radiation level in my home of 0.09–0.11 μSv/h.

When I stick it inside the dryer right after it finishes a cycle (while the clothes are still inside), it registers a radiation level of 0.16–0.18 μSv/h.

What happens during the dryer cycle that accounts for this reading? From what I understand it has something to do with trapping radon, but how exactly does this happen?

Comment: Is your dryer burning some form of fossil fuel? Piped gas?

Comment: Was your dryer made from radioactive steel from a former nuclear power plant? ;-)

Comment: It’s an electric dryer, fairly old. I did make the mistake of not taking a reading before a cycle is run (very scientific, I know) but will do that when I get home tonight

Comment: Do note that at higher temperatures the detectors will get more background radiation.

Comment: Just a thought, but is there a required operating temperature range for the instrument?

Comment: Check near the lint trap. Many fibers hold on to dust particles and such.

Comment: After you take out the clothes, what do the dryer and clothes read as? How about just before running?

Comment: Have you tried checking your laundry detergent? There is some evidence that laundry detergent is radioactive naturally. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1687850714000892

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent I cannot imagine a good connection between the temperature and the background radiation measurement (other than a broken detector or an out of specified working temperature range detector)

Comment: Anyway, I am setting the same experiment as soon as my wife is done with the dryer. Our dryer has heatpump instead of a resistive heating elements. Let's see.

Comment: @fraxinus thermal excitation of the detector elements.

Comment: What is the count rate of you device at 0.10 uSv?

Comment: how many of us have a Geiger counter at home?

Answer (score 269, accepted):

Uranium and thorium in heavy rocks have a decay chain which includes a three-day isotope of radon. If a building has materials with some chemically-insignificant mixture of uranium and thorium, such as concrete or granite, then the radon can diffuse out of the material into the air. This is part of your normal background radiation, unless you have accidentally built a concrete basement with granite countertops and poor air exchange with the outdoors, in which case the radon can accumulate.

When radon does decay, the decays leave behind ionized atoms of the heavy metals polonium, lead, and bismuth. These ions neutralize by reacting with the air. Here my chemistry is weak, but my assumption is that they are most likely to oxide, and I assume further that the oxide molecules are electrically polarized, like the water molecule (the stable oxide of hydrogen) is polarized.

Polarized or polarizable objects are attracted to strong electric fields, even when the polarized object is electrically neutral. Imagine a static electric field around a positive charge. A dipole nearby will feel a torque until its negative end points towards the static positive charge. But because the field gets weaker away from the static charge, there’s now more attractive force on the negative end of the dipole than there is repulsive force on the positive end, so the dipole accelerates towards the stronger field. If you used to have a cathode-ray television, you may remember the way the positively-charged screen would attract dust much more than other nearby surfaces.

Clothes dryers are very effective at making statically charged surfaces. (Dryer sheets help.)  So when radon and its temporary decay products are blown through the dryer, electrically-polarized molecules tend to be attracted to the charged surfaces. The decay chain is

| isotope | half-life | decay mode |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 222-Rn | 3.8 days | alpha |
| 218-Po | 3.1 minutes | alpha |
| 214-Pb | 27 minutes | beta |
| 214-Bi | 20 minutes | beta |
| 214-Po | microseconds | alpha |
| 210-Pb | years | irrelevant |

If your Geiger counter is actually detecting radiation, it's almost certainly the half-hour lead and bismuth.  Constructing a decay curve would make a neat home experiment (but challenging given what you've told us here).

True story: I was once prevented from leaving a neutron-science facility at Los Alamos after the seat of my pants set off a radiation alarm on exit.  This was odd because the neutron beam had been off for weeks.  It was a Saturday, so the radiation safety technician on call didn't arrive for half an hour — at which point I was clean, so the detective questions began.  I had spent the day sitting on a plastic step stool.  The tech looked at it, said that radon's decay products are concentrated by static electricity, and told me that I needed to get a real chair.

Comment: Very detailed answer, thanks! Am I understanding correctly that constructing a decay curve would let me find the half-life and therefore identify the exact isotope?

Comment: Yes, but because the bismuth is produced as the lead decays, the curve is more complicated than a simple exponential. Also since your data seem pretty noisy, you’ll need some largeish number of trials to get a good fit. But if you (or a junior aspiring scientist in your household) had an hour or two to sit next to your dryer and write down the reading once or twice a minute, I’d be very interested to see it.

Comment: Do you think the door being open/closed would affect the readings? I could set up a GoPro inside and hope no one starts the dryer on accident :p

Comment: Oh, that would be perfect. If you can automate the data collection, go for four half-lives. I will remind myself what the curve is supposed to look like, and we can get together again when you have some data. This sounds like fun.

Comment: I think this answer is worth an upvote just for the anecdote at the end alone.

Comment: @march ONE TIME I GOT RADON ON MY BUTT

Comment: Related: a recent [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Radiation/comments/13futi6/analysis_of_radon_decay_progeny_in_dryer_lint/) about radioactivity in dryer lint basically agrees, though it claims that the attraction is because the decay products are currently charged (after losing an alpha particle). I don't know enough to evaluate that vs the attraction of polarized oxides!
Post is worth a look either way for the beautiful comparison of predicted vs measured activity.

Comment: @mbrig The reason I speculate about polarizable molecules is that the timescale for free ions should be sub-second. The radon itself is neutral and chemically inert during its three-day life. My instinct is that a lone vapor-phase polonium ion should also become neutral much faster than it could attract to a surface. I haven't done any math about it, though. Your reddit link looks interesting.

Comment: @mbrig If the attraction does take place in the brief time that the daughter nucleus is ionized, you could change the efficiency of a filter by changing the sign of its charge. The alpha decays create $2-$ ions, while the beta decays create $1+$ ions — at least in the "sudden approximation" where the electron cloud is undisturbed by the decay.

Comment: What a fantastic answer..

Comment: @Marsroverr if you are concerned about someone else starting it, unplug the machine and put a note. For extra paranoia, tape over the socket.

Comment: At a nuclear power plant I've visited, they have an underground corridor between one of the units and the spent fuel storage building. They have a problem where the radon decay products in that corridor get stuck in people's trouser legs and trip the exit alarm when they try to leave. Around 10-20 % of people who walk through the corridor end up tripping the alarm.

Comment: You may want to get your house tested for radon. You should be able to buy a kit and test at home yourself. It’s easy, and remediation often isn’t that expensive (a lot cheaper than the health impacts that radon can bring in any case). We had remediation done in our house and I’m very glad we did.

Answer (score 12):

```
Branch & Decay  Nuclide  Half-life    
                 
                Rn-222   3.823 d      
(100.0 % alpha)   |                   
                Po-218   3.050 m      
(99.98 % alpha)   |                   
                Pb-214   26.80 m      
(100.0 % beta)    |                   
                Bi-214   19.90 m      
(99.98 % beta)    |                   
                Po-214   164.3 us     
(100.0 % alpha)   |                   
                Pb-210   22.30 a      
(100.0 % beta)    |                   
                Bi-210   5.012 d      
(100.0 % beta)    |                   
                Po-210   138.3 d      
    (alpha)       |                   
                Pb-206   stable
```

Most Radon floats around for 4 days or so then becomes house dust. It or one of the productsis attracted to the static build up in your washing machine. It may be that you live in a high radon area. Sample your house dust it is probably higher than background too.